# What is the minimum duration between 2 exact alarm trigger for Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using `AlarmManager.setExact` for triggering repeating alarm on API level 21 (lollypop) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

But my broadcast receiver not receiving pending intent consistently.

**Is there any restrictions on duration between 2 exact alarm trigger?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while i found that the only restriction apply for `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` on API level 23. From docs "Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes."

Also `AlarmManager.setExact` on API level 21 Android 5.0 has some bugs associated with it which is later fixed on API Level 22, Android 5.1 (LOLLIPOP_MR1)